# Porque existem palavras com consoantes mudas no meio?

Tags: ortografia

Vi que `Contato` e `Contacto` existem na língua portuguesa, e ambas estão corretas.

No Brasil é comum usar o `Contato` já em Portugal é usado `Contacto`.

Porque existem palavras com consoantes mudas no meio? No caso acima a letra `c`.

Existem casos por exemplo que tem a letra `p`, `b` entre outras consoantes.

Comment: Se eu não me engano eles realmente pronunciam esse **c**.

Comment: Penso que se deveriam acrescentar as tags 'etimologia' e 'fonética' a esta pergunta.

Comment: Continuam a existir muitas palavras que levam esse `c` em português europeu, mesmo depois do novo acordo. O `c` foi mantido sempre que ele é lido, como é o caso do exemplo da pergunta, `contacto`, bem como outros tantos: `facto`, `pacto`, `bactéria`...

Comment: Note que palavras com `P` que sofreram mudanças pelo mesmo motivo do `C`, no entanto algumas preservaram tanto a fonética quanto a escrita, como *egipcio*, já a palavra *egito* perdeu o `p`. Poderia editar o titulo e adicionar para algo como: *Porque existem palavras com a letra C e P no meio?* Já que parecem a mesma situação.

Comment: Existem palavras com a letra `b`. Somente citei com a letra `C` pq foi a que me lembrei.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, penso que se se acrescentarem todas as consoantes mudas, c, p, b,... isso irá alterar o teor da pergunta, além de exigir uma resposta muito extensa. Penso que a pergunta está bem assim, mais focada.

Comment: @SérgioPereira Então talvez eu tenha feito confusão, mas achei que todas situações, com b, p, c, ... eram casos principalmente de influencia fonética (acho que em Portugal algumas delas usam o som com as consoantes), estou enganado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, em Portugal algumas consoantes são sonoras, mas há muitas excepções. Por exemplo, em ‘apto’, o ‘p’ é sonoro, mas em ‘excepto’ já não. Não sei se existe uma regra para as excepções, e por isso pensei que explicá-las todas numa só resposta seria difícil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pouca explicação se tem para esse fenômeno, mas a origem é a seguinte.

> No século 16 foi iniciada a introdução gradual na ortografia
>   portuguesa de consoantes mudas de origem latina e de grafemas de
>   origem grega por motivações de erudição etimológica e sem qualquer
>   expetativa de consequências fonéticas.

Ou seja trata-se de influências de outros idiomas (principalmente grego) durante o século XVI.

---

De acordo com a nova norma, as consoantes mudas não devem mais ser utilizadas, e já é obrigatório em textos oficiais, isso para aquelas que não são pronunciadas, a que você deu como exemplo, é pronunciada e precisa ser escrita.

A maior parte das escolas, jornais e editoras estão utilizando, ou melhor, deixando de utilizar as consoantes mudas nas palavras. Alguns escritores por sua vez, optaram por continuar utilizando as consoantes, indo contra a regra.

Pelo Novo Acordo Ortográfico, a grafia das palavras com consoantes *"mudas"* passa a respeitar as **pronúncias cultas da língua**.

**Alguns exemplos**

- Acção (ação)
- Acto (ato)
- Adopção (adoção)
- óptimo (ótimo)
- Correcto (correto)
- Correcção, (correção)

Porém, só com o tempo para que a regra seja utilizada em definitivo.

Comment: Então essas palavras passam a ser consideradas erradas?

Comment: Acredito que sim.

Comment: @LucasMotta A publicação só não responde ao _porquê_ de o `c` estar lá.

Comment: @JNat e Lucas, tenho quase certeza que é por causa da pronuncia e talvez "algumas" palavras tenho a pronuncia modificada.

Comment: @JNat ajustei a resposta.

Comment: @LucasMotta o texto não parece tão grande, você poderia dar contexto ao link? Tal como solicitado em http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer ? Obrigado pela resposta, pelo que li parece que está correta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade não, ele pediu a origem, e esta ali, foi herança de outra lingua, isso aconteceu no sec 16.

Comment: @LucasMotta eu sei disso, mas links podem quebrar, o que estou tentando lhe incentivar é a fazer uma resposta mais completa, acaso o "link quebre", como é dito no how-to-answer. Apenas para não perdermos a informação. Não é na questão da resposta. (não fui eu quem lhe deu o -1)

Comment: Mas a resposta ta ali... ele não vai encontrar mais nada sobre consoantes mudas naquele link. apenas outras informações sobre outras mudanças, nada que tenha no link vai ser proveitoso para esse contexto, apenas para agregar informações a ele.

Comment: *Contacto* e *facto* são duas exce(p)ções, porque em Portugal fazem parte da pronuncia,

Comment: Acho uma vergonha e uma pena que séculos de aprendizado e tradição ortográfica venham jogados fora. Sinto pena das pessoas mais adultas, que aprenderam a língua portuguesa de um modo e agora, entrarão em confusão em nome duma simplificação, de alterações desnecessárias, tornando-a, por vezes, quase esquizofrênica.

Answer (score 9):

Certas consoantes mudas têm origem no étimo latino de onde a palavra provém.

Por exemplo, ‘acto’ vem do latim ‘actu’, assim como ‘contacto’ vem do latim ‘contactu’.

Em português o 'c' tornou-se mudo, em alguns casos. Em Portugal e no Brasil, ‘acto’ diz-se [ato], mas ‘contacto’ pode ser ouvido de ambas as formas, conforme as regiões.

Curiosamente, em inglês o ‘c’ continua sonoro: ‘act’, ‘contact’.

Noutras línguas latinas a sequência 'ct' pode ter sido alterada, como em italiano, onde foi substituída por duplo ‘t’: ‘fatto’ e ‘contatto’. A dupla consoante, em italiano, marca uma curta pausa.

No Acordo Ortográfico português de 1990 desaparecem algumas consoantes mudas. ‘Acto’ passa a escrever-se ‘ato’, e ‘acção’ passa a ‘ação’.

Noutros casos onde a ortografia é semelhante, mas a pronúncia, pelo menos em Portugal, não é, não houve alteração.

Por exemplo, ‘contacto’ e ‘facto’ mantêm a grafia. Em Portugal, o ‘c’ em ‘facto’ ou ‘factual’ não é mudo.